# Is it possible to give a custom build error with T4?

Tags: c#, t4

So something like

```
<#
GiveError("Something is not right");
#>
```

which would then show as compilation error in the error list among the other compilation errors. This could be helpful to provide the programmer with more specific information about what is going wrong, instead of just exiting with a `ErrorGeneratingOutput` message in the target file.

Comment: I never used T4, but it is C# so you should can use "throw new Exception("Error");"

Comment: @Noren: That wouldn't be a compilation error.

Comment: You can generate code that doesn't compile using the `#error` pragma - is that what you're after? It's not quite the same as halting generation entirely though. (I'm not sure which you're looking for...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Halting the generation and giving the error right away is what I'm after, but anything that comes close is worth knowing about. The suggestion with the error pragma is not bad!

Comment: Okay, will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about T4 generation specifically, so I can't help in terms of halting the generation process with a useful message, but you may find it's better just to generate a `#error` pragma, e.g

```
#error No configuration found for X
```

Ideally the rest of the file should still be valid (or have more error reports) so that you end up with just the errors you want to report.

One benefit of this over halting is that if there are multiple problems to fix, the developer may be able to fix them all in one pass. The downside is that (depending on what you're generating) a single configuration problem may cause thousands of errors, unhelpfully.